# Foundation 4 on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zurb-foundation, quirks-mode

I have made a website using [Foundation 4 CSS Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/support.html) - everything is perfect on Chrome, Opera, Firefox... but on Internet Explorer 9 it's a disaster.

It helps when I **switch from quirks mode to IE9 mode** - but it has to be done manually.
Can I force IE to use appriopropriate mode? Any ideas how to fix this issue?
Foundation website is working in IE9 someway. There is support for IE9, but mine enters into quirks mode somehow, I don't know why - tried some tricks (adding same HTML comments as on the [Foundation site](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/support.html)) but all failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quirks mode is controlled by the doctype.  This is what an HTML5 doctype looks like and should put you in Standards mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The wikipedia has a nice chart showing what does and does not trigger quirks mode:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types

Comment: OMG, my stupid mistake: selected "doctype HTML5" in Textpattern CMS and thought it will generate it automatically... But I've to add this manually to my template. Now everything works.

Thank a lot - I was reading website generated code but never paid attention at the beginnig (doctype was obvious...). Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Also...

You can force edge mode in meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

And make sure 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is disabled in "Tools > Compatibility View settings" if testing the site from a local web server on your network.